Under which scenario (if any) could Donald Trump seek a third term in office if elected in 2024 and be considered the official president of the US?
The twenty-second amendment to the United States Constitution specifically limits the number of times a person can be elected to the office of the president of the United States.
However, Trump has over the years suggested seeking three terms in office, originally claiming he was entitled to a third term because "they spied on my campaign".
Assuming a Republican win of the president and both Houses in 2024, what are the possible pathways to electing Trump for a third term?
The possible pathways I see are the following:

Repealing the 22nd amendment. This would take an aggressive long-term campaign to undermine democracy until both houses are at least two-thirds Republican and three-quarters of the states are Republican-controlled. From my understanding, this would likely take many years, possibly longer than the lifetime of Trump.
Ignoring the 22nd amendment and using a legal argument akin to "they spied on my campaign" to argue that his first term was not a full term and therefore his second term is really his first term. I am not sure which court would decide on this, and whether even this supreme court would be persuaded by this argument.
A more aggressive/abusive use of presidential immunity to threaten the Supreme Court into giving him a free pass to pursue a third term

I am likely missing some other obvious pathways, and I have no idea how likely any of these situations are. So in your answer, please try to give a rough indication of the likelihood of each series of events occurring.

Under the scenario in which SCOTUS decides that based on something-something. Because one can be sure that if he were to seek a 3rd term that will be challenged in courts.

Of course, as Trump sometimes does when he gets cornered on some statement, he might say this was in jest too.

This question doesn't depend on Donald Trump. He hasn't even secured a second term yet. And we should avoid useless speculation. The question then reduces to what legal ways are there for circumventing a constitutional amendment and if it's not already been asked the answer would probably be that you need a very big majority for that.

Maybe possibilities: 1. He gets elected , one year later it is found he was cheating and gets fired. Next election, he has only served for five years. 2. Same, but after one year he has an unfortunate accident and spends three years in a coma, then recovers without any damage. Not sure if this would be within the rules, but the second one would be within the spirit.

@gnasher729 it doesn't matter how soon one leaves office after being elected -- or even whether one resigns before being sworn in.  The constitution provides that nobody may be elected more than twice.

Trump can not do that. USA courts seem very traditionalist, how do they interpret law. Look the other hot case, the gun control. There are some anti-gun guys saying that "right to bear arms" means that you can join the USA army. Courts say that no, it has always meant that you can buy a gun like a phone. Same is for the presidency. It does not matter, what legal argumentation is coming up, courts will say no, there is no escape from the 2 term rule.

Barring any unexpected lawfare results (like SCOTUS just finding a loophole in the 22nd based on something I can't fathom right now), as far as I can tell some Conservatives are arguing that the 22nd should be plainly repealed. I saw no consideration given to the timeline in such "Trump 2028" pieces though.
N.B. this piece mentioned there was such a legislative proposal in 2003, and that it was defeated then. Snopes has a more detailed recent history (although only up to 2014). The attempted repeal generally came from a small number of proponents, some of whom 'bipartisanly' [repeatedly] proposed it e.g. during both Clinton and G.W. Bush years. And then another Representative proposed it several years in a row during Obama's presidency. OTOH none of these fared well:

According to our survey, not a single one of these proposals was ever so much as brought to a vote before Congress (they were all referred to committee and languished there), much less passed and sent to the states for ratification.

FWTW, one law firm claims that if a President were to be "chosen" by House of Representatives e.g. in a tied election [tied electoral-college wise]... that doesn't count as an election for the purpose of the 22nd, based on the exact wording of the Amendment. It's hard to say how well this theory would work out in a real court case.
For the sake of completeness, the latter source also says that one could also ascend to the presidency by running for VP in such circumstances, i.e. after two full terms. And then the figurehead POTUS steps aside or dies. Whether Trump would be even inclined to somehow partly mimic the Russia 2008 arrangements [when Putin downgraded to PM] is pretty debatable for a variety of reasons, and from my limited search I've not seen this suggested in the case of Trump [2028].  (As for the argument in the previous para, I'm not claiming that this argument is correct or that it would hold water in a real court case. But they've essentially not been tested in courts, so some law firm is willing to advance them on a website. Of course, some lawyers were willing to advance all sorts of Trump election cases in 2020 in actual courts, so that's not necessarily saying much.) For another (positive) take on whether two-term presidents can be VP and so then accede to the presidency again [by POTUS dying or resigning], see Coenen (2015). The legal argument there is expounded at much more length--59 pages! But to give out a quick idea how that argument rolls despite the 12th amendment: part of it is that "constitutionally ineligible" in the 12th doesn't refer to the 22nd amendment (or any other subsequent amendments), but only to the base text of the Constitution (see e.g. p. 1288 in Coenen).
Likewise the aforementioned law firm suggests that another/3rd avenue is for both the POTUS and VP to be 'fake' runners who intend to both resign and the 'real' president could then be again effectively chosen by the House of Representatives as their Speaker (who is the 3rd in the line of succession). This one is perhaps the least debatable wrt the Constitution text, but also least likely humanly speaking.

If they want to go down the rabbit hole of being chosen by the house of representatives they open up an even bigger one of someone being selected as a VP replacement and moving up the president after the current one resigns. While it wasn't to get around term limits Gerald Ford did become president in this manner.

@JoeW: yeah [and that's discussed in the latter source], but personally I don't see Trump
"pulling a 2008 Putin", i.e. run as VP, due to his ego, not wanting to be 2nd on anything. So that's why I left out such extra discusison.

The 12th amendment rules that out as well. "But no person constitutionally ineligible to the office of President shall be eligible to that of Vice-President of the United States." https://constitution.congress.gov/constitution/amendment-12/

@JoeW: yeah, but that law firm argues that "constitutionally ineligible" doesn't mean the plain reading, just like they argue that being "chosen" by the HoR is not the same as being elected... "The 22nd Amendment only requires that someone not be elected to the Presidency more than twice. Someone who was elected to two terms on his own is still eligible to be Vice President and to rise to the Presidency upon the death, resignation or removal of the President."

And I am not referring to that statement, rather the idea that someone could be put in as a replacement VP not as part of the normal election cycle as in the case of Gerald Ford after Spiro Agnew resigned.
